# How to create a unique node from result of a query in Cypher language

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a single node with squeezes pointing to it, coming from the query result below:

```
MATCH (e:EXP)-[s:Was_selected]->
      (g:GNE)-[p:Has_interaction]-(h:GNE)-
      [:Was_clusterized]-(c:CLUSTER)-
      [:Was_represented]-(b:BP) 
WHERE p.combined_score > 800 
WITH DISTINCT g, COUNT(distinct h) AS score WHERE score > 50
CREATE (g)-[:AS_HUBS]->(HUBS)
RETURN g
```

But the result is a one nodes of type HUBs for each g(GNE).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're query is quite complex, so let's create a simpler example for experimenting:

```
CREATE
  (a1:A {name: 'a1'}),
  (a2:A {name: 'a2'})
```

To create a hub between the two nodes, we use the following query:

```
MATCH (a:A)
WITH collect(a) AS as
CREATE (hub:Hub {name: 'hub'})
WITH as, hub
UNWIND as AS a
CREATE (hub)<-[:AS_HUBS]-(a)
RETURN *
```

This will create as single `Hub` for all `A` nodes. Explanation: we [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/aggregation/#aggregation-collect) the results to a single row (into a list), create a single `Hub`, then [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) the row and create a relationship for each `A` node.

[image]

If we adapt the approach for your use case, we get the following query:

```
MATCH (e:EXP)-[s:Was_selected]->
      (g:GNE)-[p:Has_interaction]-(h:GNE)-
      [:Was_clusterized]-(c:CLUSTER)-
      [:Was_represented]-(b:BP) 
WHERE p.combined_score > 800 
WITH DISTINCT g, COUNT(distinct h) AS score
WHERE score > 50
WITH collect(g) AS gs
CREATE (hub:Hub {name: 'hub'})
WITH gs, hub
UNWIND gs AS g
CREATE (g)-[:AS_HUBS]->(hub)
RETURN *
```